# Dealing with jquery locator in selenium webdriver, ruby

Tags: ruby, jquery-selectors, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying jquery locator in selenium webdriver with ruby. Here is my code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => :firefox)
driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")

# input.lst is the search input text in google.com
selector = "input.lst"

# get element from the locator
element = driver.execute_script("return $(#{selector}).get(0);")

# type "google" into the input text
element.send_keys "google"
```

I tried element = driver.find_element() and it works fine so I think maybe there is a more general way to do all the jquery locator. That's why I try execute_script. However, it seems that the execute_script function is broken. I got many error from sun.reflect, java.lang or org.openqa...

P/S: If anyone know how to add_location_strategy in webdriver, pls tell me about it :D. It was so brilliant in selenium rc and I can't find a way to implement it in webdriver.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you showed us the errors you get. The code looks fine except Google doesn't use jQuery on their front page.

Comment: Here is what I got:
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl():-2:in `newInstance0'
: $ is not defined (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace informati
on) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError)
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
Exception)
....
I just use jquery locator for selecting the element.

Answer (score 1):

After navigating to the desired page, but before using jQuery:

```
# load the JavaScript file into memory as a string
jQuerify = ...

# add jQuery to the current page
driver.execute_async_script(jQuerify)
```

Here is the JavaScript file mentioned:

```
/*** dynamically load jQuery ***/
(function(callback) {
    var JQUERY_URL = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var script=document.createElement('script');
        script.src = JQUERY_URL;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = (function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState 
                    || this.readyState == 'loaded' 
                    || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback(); // tell WebDriver we are done
                head.removeChild(script);
            }
        });
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
})(arguments[arguments.length - 1]);
```

This snippet will be pasted into the body of an anonymous function by WebDriver, placing jQuery in the global scope.  The file contents should be cached for repeated invocations.

(Borrowed heavily from [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet))

Oh and generally, you should stick to the [Ruby API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method) when selecting elements.  Using JavaScript directly is considered a workaround and runs counter to the spirit of WebDriver.